# Как просто и правильно развернуть php на сервере?

Tags: php, развертывание, непрерывная-интеграция

Пишу `php` файлы на локальном пк (проверяю на `openeserver'е`) и хочу в несколько кликов отправлять их на удалённый сервер в конкретную директорию, что бы они там работали. На сервере установлен `git`, но вчера провозился весь день и создалось впечатление, что `git` не совсем для этого. Сегодня [продолжил попытки](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa), впечатление осталось примерно тем же (упёрся в "*No such file or directory*"). Я так понимаю остаётся только вариант писать собственный скрипт и предавать файлы по `ftp`? Какие варианты ещё есть?

Comment: Установите на сервак jenkins, добавьте свой проект и в один клик перезаливайте. Или можно настроить чтоб после каждого пуша перезаписывался проект

Answer (score 0):

Для таких нужд рекомендую поднять `CI`, а конкретно [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/)

Если вы учитесь в школе или являетесь студентом, то советую оформить `GitHub Pro Student`. Там куча фич среди которых есть бесплатный улучшенный `Travis`. (Хотя он и так бесплатный, но с некоторыми ограничениями как раз связанные с деплоем)